# Showing the name of a named cell automatically in an adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have to automatically sum up the total of a product in my spreadsheet.

For example, If A2 was named `Potato`, and had a value of £10, in cell A1 I would like to be able to see the name of A2 automatically (`Potato`).

This way I can ensure my formula will always work, as it would require some effort to change the named cell's name.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733123/retrieving-cell-name-in-excel

Comment: This is perhaps an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you perhaps edit the formula to use the named range? Or something with `Indirect`?

Comment: I feel i have tried everything, including reading about all the possible formula in the 'insert function'. Address, Row, Code and lots more.

Comment: Leviathan, That code worked....ish. When i '=' the cell thats named with the new function is will bring the [name] back. however, when you drag the function down is makes the first function absolute $$ (i.e. the name of the cell). is there a way of adapting the code so avoid this?